# How to inspect Microsoft.Windows.Themes

Tags: wpf, windows-themes

It's no secret that wpf exposes it's default themes , for example here's a shortened version of 
how a checkbox template looks

```
xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes"

<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
     <BulletDecorator>
          <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <theme:BulletChrome />
          </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
          <ContentPresenter />
     </BulletDecorator>
</ControlTemplate>
```

gee .. that's great and most help full (NOT!)

i actually wanted to see how the check mark path looks like , 
is there any way to observe the inner content of :

> Microsoft.Windows.Themes

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the default Microsoft XAML that resides inside the `Style`s, `Template`s, etc. for the WPF controls, then please take a look at the [Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) page at MSDN.

I believe that the latest ones can be found on the [WPF Document Samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes) page at MSDN.

However, I cannot confirm that these come from the `Microsoft.Windows.Themes` dll, so this *might* not be what you are after.

Comment: no it's not , iv'e already downloaded these themes , the question was about elements in them .
You see i'm looking for the inner style and template of <theme:BulletChrome> which resides in the Aero theme.